# "The provided key element does not match the schema" DynamoDB (boto3) error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to query items from my DynamoDB using boto3.

The table looks like this:

[DynamoDB Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qip9.png)

And the code I'm running is:

```
import boto3

TableName = "lightblue_ble_indication_data"
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
DB = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

table = DB.Table(TableName)

response = table.get_item(Key={'ble_device_name': "LUMEN18BLE", 'timestamp': "1573742965303"})

response['Item']
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Unfortunately in the table image you showed above, it's not clear what is "timestamp"'s type. Could it be that it is a number, and not a string? In your code you tried to pass it as a string which will be an error if it actually needs to be a number.

Comment: You're right, it's a number! Works fine now, thank you!

Comment: So for posterity, I'll post an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the key which you passed, `{'ble_device_name': "LUMEN18BLE", 'timestamp': "1573742965303"}` does not match the schema of the table - i.e., the key defined for it. This either means that the names `ble_device_name` or `timestamp` do not match the actual key attributes of this table, or that the values you chose for them have an incorrect type.

The image you attached proves that `ble_device_name` or `timestamp` are the correct key attribute names, so that's not the problem. It also shows that `ble_device_name` has a string type, as you passed it. The only possibility left is that you passed a string for `timestamp`, while in the table it was declared to be a number. You just need to drop the quotes around the value `1573742965303` you are trying to pass for the timestamp, and everything should work.